# why can in TypeScript a possible number value in an interface be converted to a not possible number value in a class implementation?

Tags: typescript, implicit-conversion, language-design, type-systems

Today I ran into an unexpected TypeScript compiler behaviour. I'm wondering if it's a bug or a feature. Probably it will be the last one, but then I would like to know the rationale behind it.

If I declare an interface method with a parameter that can be a `string | number`, and create a class that implements that interface, then the class method can make that parameter only `string`.
This leads to a situation where the class implementation is not expecting a number, but the compiler allows that number to be passed.
Why is that allowed?

```
interface Foo {
    hello(value: string | number): void
}

class FooClass implements Foo {
    hello(value: string) { //notice the missing 'number'
        console.log(`hello ${value}`)
    }
}

const x = new FooClass()

x.hello("me")

//x.hello(42) this gives a compile error

const y: Foo = x

y.hello(42)
```

Comment: You can also change the interface to have `string | number` and the compiler still accepts an implementation that takes `string` only.

Comment: thanks! I think that that is an even stronger example of the weird behaviour. I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sad/funny truth about TypeScript is that it's not fully type-safe.  Some features are intentionally unsound, in places where it was felt that soundness would be a hindrance to productivity.  See ["a note on soundness" in the TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).   You've run into one such feature: [method parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).

When you have a function or method type that accepts a parameter of type `A`, the only *type safe* way to implement or extend it is to accept a parameter of a *supertype* `B` of `A`.  This is known as parameter [*contravariance*](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance): if `A` extends `B`, then `((param: B) => void) extends ((param: A) => void)`.  The subtype relationship for a function is the *opposite* of the subtype relationship for its parameters.  So given `{ hello(value: string | number): void }`, it would be safe to implement it with `{ hello(value: string | number | boolean): void }` or `{ hello(value: unknown): void}`.

But you implemented it with `{ hello(value: string): void}`; the implementation is accepting a *subtype* of the declared parameter.  That's *covariance* (the subtype relationship is the *same* for both the function and its parameters), and as you noted, that is unsafe.  TypeScript accepts *both* the safe contravariant implementation and the unsafe covariant implementation: this is called *bivariance*.

So *why* is this allowed in methods?  The answer is because a lot of commonly used types have covariant method parameters, and enforcing contravariance would cause such types to fail to form a subtype hierarchy.  The motivating example from [the FAQ entry on parameter bivariance](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) is `Array<T>`.  It is incredibly convenient to think of `Array<string>` as a subtype of, say, `Array<string | number>`.  After all, if you ask me for an `Array<string | number>`, and I hand you `["a", "b", "c"]`, that should be acceptable, right?  Well, not if you are strict about method parameters.  After all, an `Array<string | number>` should let you `push(123)` to it, whereas an `Array<string>` shouldn't.  Method parameter covariance is allowed for this reason.

---

So what can you do?  Before TypeScript 2.6, *all functions* acted this way.  But then they introduced the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types).  If you enable that (and you should), then *function* parameter types are checked covariantly (safe), while *method* parameter types are still checked bivariantly (unsafe).

The difference between a function and a method in the type system is fairly subtle.  The types `{ a(x: string): void }` and `{ a: (x: string) => void }` are the same except that in the first type `a` is a method, and in the second, `a` is a function-valued property.  And therefore the `x` in the first type will be checked bivariantly, and the `x` in the second type will be checked contravariantly.  Other than that, though, they behave essentially the same.  You can implement a method as a function-valued property or vice versa.

That leads to the following potential solution to the issue here:

```
interface Foo {
    hello: (value: string | number) => void 
}
```

Now `hello` is declared to be a function and not a method type.  But the class implementation can still be a method.  And now you get the expected error:

```
class FooClass implements Foo {
    hello(value: string) { // error!
//  ~~~~~
//  string | number is not assignable to string
        console.log(`hello ${value}`)
    }
}
```

And if you leave it like that, you get an error later on:

```
const y: Foo = x; // error!
//    ~
// FooClass is not a Foo
```

If you fix `FooClass` so that `hello()` accepts a supertype of `string | number`, those errors go away:

```
class FooClass implements Foo {
    hello(value: string | number | boolean) { // okay now
        console.log(`hello ${value}`)
    }
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlA9gG2Eg3gWAChCkSkBLYAFwgCcAzBZAMTTV2NM4AsIMM0AXEgAUANxAYArhCFRKNCgHMkAHyTBJYAEa0AlEgC8APiSi0ZACYcSAX0LWk8DCChQkLNAGFnr8mBgYEJBUbh7sBJzcvPxiEtKy8kr6OEgA9KlItDRoNACEDpGk6SQAfmVlBYVpGUhyCsDKahratORuwGiUSC5QZIqgWoFIlGx1SpWF8GjAUJgQAHT8isIABjx8bAAkOOJSEDYruhNIdhGkpw5TM10AHobqEADu7qzePcL69mckN-PrMQAiSAAo5Eb6OaZyJAATyEYQMSBuAG5qpkaNk8g5iqQSliMh43r4yO1Ot0XmgHNC-tE0MIACwAJlBFwIoEgsEYqEwwCYZDu+DBnAo1HonLCAqqSH+ghEu3itUSDVU6k0Oho+mMpnMVnBLM4Th65MJbjI-kCwUooVY4Ul0tiewS9UaKpaNGVWlYgRAwGSx31kLmizQyzWNKQ2zl+0Ox1OnD1pCuULuCOATyNPigHy+nF+dqBEBB2YTkK6sPJ92RlOpG3pTK+LMIQA)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I'm happy there is a way to deal with this. I just find it unfortunate that it is the 'function property in interface' instead of the interface method that does the 'correct' behavior